# StopWatch is not working when I click on Stop Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, javascript-objects

It's difficult to identify the exact issue, My StopWatch is not working when I click on Stop Button and wait for some second then I click on start button then I see that my second is working fine but minutes is not working properly. please check that is there any issue

```js
    let start = document.getElementById("start");
    let stop = document.getElementById("stop");
    let reset = document.getElementById("reset");
    let h3 = document.getElementById("h3");
    let time = document.getElementById("time");
    let h3CreateMin = document.createElement("h3");
    let h3CreateHour = document.createElement("h3");
    let milisecond = document.getElementById("milisecond");
    let second = document.getElementById("second");
    let minSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let minSpanSigin = document.createElement("span");
    let hourSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let hourSpanSigin = document.createElement("span");
    
    let secStart = 0;
    let miliSecStart = 0;
    let minStart = 0;
    let hourStart = 0;
    let s = true;
    
    start.addEventListener("click", function () {
    
      reset.style.display = "block";
      stop.style.display = "block";
      start.style.display = "none";
    
      miliSecondStop = setInterval(() => {
        let miliSec = miliSecStart + 1;
        milisecond.innerText = miliSec;
        miliSecStart = miliSec;
        if (miliSecStart === 99) {
          miliSecStart = 0;
        }
      }, 10);
    
      // Sec Start
      secondStop = setInterval(() => {
        let sec = secStart + 1;
        secStart = sec;
        second.innerText = secStart;
        if (sec === 60) {
          secStart = 0;
        }
      }, 1000);
    
    
    //   Min Start
      minStop = setInterval(() => {
        let min = minStart + 1;
        if (s === true) {
          time.prepend(h3CreateMin);
        }
        h3CreateMin.style.display = "block";
        h3CreateMin.append(minSpan);
        minSpan.classList = "value";
        h3CreateMin.classList = "time_s_m_h";
        h3CreateMin.append(minSpanSigin);
        minSpanSigin.classList = "sigin";
        minSpanSigin.innerText = "M";
        minStart = min;
        minSpan.innerText = min;
        if (min === 60) {
          minStart = 0;
        }
        s = false;
      }, 60000);
      // 60000
    
      // Hour Start
      hourStop = setInterval(() => {
        let hour = hourStart + 1;
        time.prepend(h3CreateHour);
        h3CreateHour.style.display = "block";
        h3CreateHour.classList = "time_s_m_h";
        h3CreateHour.append(hourSpan);
        hourSpan.classList = "value";
        h3CreateHour.append(hourSpanSigin);
        hourSpanSigin.classList = "sigin";
        hourSpanSigin.innerText = "H";
        hourSpan.innerText = hour;
        hourStart = hour;
        if (hour === 24) {
          hourStart = 0;
        }
      }, 60000);
      //    3600000
    });
    stop.addEventListener("click", function () {
      start.style.display = "block";
      stop.style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(miliSecondStop);
      clearInterval(secondStop);
      clearInterval(minStop);
      clearInterval(hourStop);
    });
    
    reset.addEventListener("click", function () {
      start.style.display = "block";
      stop.style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(miliSecondStop);
      miliSecStart = 0;
      milisecond.innerText = "00";
    
      clearInterval(secondStop);
      secStart = 0;
      second.innerText = 0;
    
      clearInterval(minStop);
      minStart = 0;
      h3CreateMin.style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(hourStop);
      hourStart = 0;
      h3CreateHour.style.display = "none";
    });
```

```css
    *{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    }
    main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FEA600;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    }
    main div:first-child{
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    main div:first-child h1, main div:first-child h2,main div:first-child h3{
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    main div:first-child #time{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
    main div:first-child #time .time_s_m_h{
    display: flex;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 8, 255); */
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    }
    main div:first-child h3 .sigin{
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* border: 1px solid green; */
    }
    main div:first-child h3 #milisecond{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    /* border: 1px solid green; */
    }
    main div:last-child{
    display: flex;
    
    }
    main div:last-child button{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #FEA600;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 10px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    #stop,#reset{
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
HTML 

    <body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <h1>STOP WATCH</h1>
            <!-- <h2>Vanilla JavaScript stopwatch</h2> -->
            <div id="time">
                <h3 class="time_s_m_h">
                    <span id="second" class="value">0</span>
                    <span class="sigin">S</span> 
                </h3>
                <h3 id="h3">
                    <span id="milisecond" class="sigin">00</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div id="btnDiv">
            <button id="start">Start</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I suggest using a single timer and the system clock to track elapsed time.  Incrementing values on separate timers (H,M,S) is sure to cause synchronization problems and cumulative inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one timer to count.
Your code does not work exactly for second too.
If you click start and stop quickly, scond label will not increase.
It's because when you click start and stop, all timer will be reset.
So you should use one timer.

```js
let start = document.getElementById("start");
    let stop = document.getElementById("stop");
    let reset = document.getElementById("reset");
    let h3 = document.getElementById("h3");
    let time = document.getElementById("time");
    let h3CreateMin = document.createElement("h3");
    let h3CreateHour = document.createElement("h3");
    let milisecond = document.getElementById("milisecond");
    let second = document.getElementById("second");
    let minSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let minSpanSigin = document.createElement("span");
    let hourSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let hourSpanSigin = document.createElement("span");    
    let miliSec = 0;
    let s = true;
    
    start.addEventListener("click", function () {
    
      reset.style.display = "block";
      stop.style.display = "block";
      start.style.display = "none";
    
      miliSecondStop = setInterval(() => {
        miliSec++;
   
        let milsecText =  miliSec % 100;
        let secText = (parseInt(miliSec / 100)) % 60;
        let minText = (parseInt(miliSec / 6000)) % 60;
        let hourText = parseInt(miliSec / 360000);
        milisecond.innerText = milsecText;      
        second.innerText = secText;       
        if(minText>0){
          time.prepend(h3CreateMin);
          h3CreateMin.style.display = "block";
          h3CreateMin.append(minSpan);
          minSpan.classList = "value";
          h3CreateMin.classList = "time_s_m_h";
          h3CreateMin.append(minSpanSigin);
          minSpanSigin.classList = "sigin";
          minSpanSigin.innerText = "M";
          minSpan.innerText = minText;   
        }
        
        if(hourText > 0){
          time.prepend(h3CreateHour);
          h3CreateHour.style.display = "block";
          h3CreateHour.classList = "time_s_m_h";
          h3CreateHour.append(hourSpan);
          hourSpan.classList = "value";
          h3CreateHour.append(hourSpanSigin);
          hourSpanSigin.classList = "sigin";
          hourSpanSigin.innerText = "H";
          hourSpan.innerText = hourText;
        }
    
      }, 10);
    });
    stop.addEventListener("click", function () {
      start.style.display = "block";
      stop.style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(miliSecondStop);

    });
    
    reset.addEventListener("click", function () {
      start.style.display = "block";
      stop.style.display = "none";
      clearInterval(miliSecondStop);
      miliSec = 0;
      milisecond.innerText = "00";
    
      

      h3CreateMin.style.display = "none";
 
      h3CreateHour.style.display = "none";
    });
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    }
    main{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #FEA600;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    }
    main div:first-child{
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    main div:first-child h1, main div:first-child h2,main div:first-child h3{
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }
    main div:first-child #time{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
    main div:first-child #time .time_s_m_h{
    display: flex;
    /* border: 1px solid rgb(0, 8, 255); */
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    }
    main div:first-child h3 .sigin{
    font-size: 2rem;
    /* border: 1px solid green; */
    }
    main div:first-child h3 #milisecond{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    /* border: 1px solid green; */
    }
    main div:last-child{
    display: flex;
    
    }
    main div:last-child button{
    padding: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #FEA600;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 10px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    #stop,#reset{
    display: none;
    }
```

```html
HTML 

    <body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <h1>STOP WATCH</h1>
            <!-- <h2>Vanilla JavaScript stopwatch</h2> -->
            <div id="time">
                <h3 class="time_s_m_h">
                    <span id="second" class="value">0</span>
                    <span class="sigin">S</span> 
                </h3>
                <h3 id="h3">
                    <span id="milisecond" class="sigin">00</span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div id="btnDiv">
            <button id="start">Start</button>
            <button id="stop">Stop</button>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```